# Extending $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ for holomorphic f to be continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Define $f: D(0,1)-> C$ to be holomorphic such that$ f(0)=0$. I want to extend  $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ to be continuous on $\overline D(0,r)$ for arbitrary $0<r<1$.

My initial guess was to define:

$g(z)= \frac{f(z)}{z}$ for non-zero $z$ but extend $g(z)$ to be $0$ for $z=0$.

But if I take $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} = f'(0)$ using L'Hopital's rule. So I think this should be the expression for $g(0)$? I wonder if:

i) L'hopital's rule is applicable to complex functions, and,

ii)Am I taking the limit incorrectly? I also do not see a use for $f(0)=0$ in my deduction so I'm rather perplexed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0)\ne0$, then the limit $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)}z$ does not exist (in $\Bbb C$). On the other hand, if $f(0)=0$, then $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)}z=f'(0)$ byt the definition of $f'$. So, extend $f$ to$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&D(0,1)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)}z&\text{ if }z\ne0\\f'(0)&\text{ if }z=0,\end{cases}\end{array}$$and then $F$ is continuous. In particular, if $r\in(0,1)$, the restriction of $F$ to $\overline{D(0,r)}$ is continuous.

Comment: @OP In fact, more is true. This extension is holomorphic